# Hibernate: how to make the passed entity Persistent

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a method like below:

```
@Override
public <T extends Entity> T saveOrHibernateUpdate(T entity) {
    if (entity.getId() == null) {
        persist(entity);
    } else {
        getSession().update(entity);
    }
    return entity;
}
```

I want to use `getSession().merge(entity)` instead of `getSession().update(entity)` inside `else` condition.

But this method is already being used by other applications. To not effect others,  the `entity` which is passed to this method should still remain persistent, how can I achieve this when I am using `merge` instead of `update`? Because `merge` will not make the passed `entity` as persistent. Any ideas?

Example:

let's say someone is using previous version of this method like below

```
person.setName("ABC");// cosider person as a detached instance with a different name
saveOrHibernateUpdate(person);
person.setName("DEF") // They don't need to call the saveOrHibernateUpdate method again after this statement because person is a persistent object. But if I change the logic to use merge instead of update, then the users of this method would still see the name as "ABC". `So I need to make person object persistent somehow`
```

Comment: I figure what you mean is: You get an object passed as a parameter which is *detached* and you want to make that very object instance *managed* within the persistence context?

Comment: Yes, I have added an example.

Comment: @JimmyB But note that I want to use merge

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate `merge()` can be used to update values. Although this method creates a copy from the passed entity object and return it. **The returned object is part of persistent context** and tracked for any changes, passed object is not tracked. So you can do the following:

```
@Override
public <T extends Entity> T saveOrHibernateUpdate(T entity) {
    if (entity.getId() == null) {
        persist(entity);
        return (T) entity;
    } else {
        Entity pEntity = (Entity) getSession().merge(entity);
        return (T) pEntity;
    }
}
```

By this way you will have the persistent object `pEntity` for many further manipulations.

Comment: Hi, thanks, question is a bit different though, how can I modify saveOrHibernateUpdate(T entity) method to have merge instead of update, but I still want the entity argument to be made persistent for later use. is that possible?

Comment: I just updated the answer. I believe that this is what you want.

Comment: Not exactly, I want entity ( the one that this method is having as an input parameter) to be persistent

Comment: If so, then you can do nothing with this method. It is a matter of previous manipulations outside of your given method.